# How to fetch OConcurrentModificationException in Server Side Javascript (OrientDB Studio)

Tags: javascript, orientdb

I developed server side javascript code in OrientDB Studio, which is inserting new vertices and edges to an existing vertex in a transaction (`db.begin()`, `db.commit()`). As soon as I am increasing the load, the log is throwing

> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConcurrentModificationException: Cannot UPDATE the record #36:0 because the version is not the latest. Probably you are updating an old record or it has been modified by another user (db=v57609 your=v57608)
>       DB name="SSD"
>       Error Code="3"

From the documentation I learned that it may happen when there are conflicts between different versions of the vertex in different transactions and that you can catch it and do retries or handle the conflict individually. But I did not find any way to do this with server-side javascript. How can I catch the exception? A simple `try {} catch()` will be ignored in this case.